# What is the difference between n-heptan (CAS 93924-37-9) and branched, linear and cyclic heptane (CAS 426260-76-6)?

Tags: organic-chemistry, safety

I am looking at the substitution of hazardous substances in my company. I would like to explain what makes the branched, linear and cyclic heptane (CAS 426260-76-6) safer than *n*-heptane (CAS 93924-37-9).

I do not know what is the influence of molecular structure of heptane on the properties of this substances. I mean here two different primers (chemical adhesion promotor) on heptane basis. One of them includes branched, linear and cyclic heptane and methylacetate mixture (this primer is not carcinogenic) and the second one n-heptane only (is carcinogenic).

Is there someone who can explain it?

Comment: Linear and n are the same.  The rest is  about flash point boiling point flammability.

Comment: After your edit I just note that both primers have n-heptane (name for linear heptane) in their formulation. So it is not clear why or  what something makes one carcinogenic and the other not.also is not clear what are you really asking. Their structure?  Their mechanism of carcinogenic potential? Safety in general

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response. I am asking about their mechanism of carcinogenic potential and safty in general. Once again. I have two primers, one of them includes only n-heptane isoalkane, cyclic alkane. The second one is a mixture of branched, cyclic and linear heptane (40-60%), methylacetat, naphtha (dearomatized and hydrodesulfonated)  and tributhyl-O-acetylcitrat. The first one is cancirogenic, the second one is not. I can not explain what causes the second mixture more safety. Both include heptan as a main substance.

Comment: Go through all the components and look for the carcinogenic ones. For safety in general you have safety datas . For the formulations trust the companies. At least now is more clear what you are asking and perhaps someone can answer